# How to do linux snapshots similar to VirtualBox guest snapshot?

Tags: linux, backup, restore, snapshot

I'm still learning how linux works so I'm constantly making mistakes, installing packages in the wrong way and whatnot. A good way of solving this is using VirtualBox and just taking snapshots from time to time and when I mess up, just return to the past snapshot, which takes a few seconds.

¿Is there a functionality like this already integrated in ubuntu or some popular distro? The whole package removal seems very complicated to me, and the dependencies are complicated to understand.

Comment: Some filesystems, btrfs in particular, support snapshots. The issue you then face is splitting up your system so you can roll back some things but not others. You want to rewind to before you installed a certain package, but you don't want to loose the bookmarks you created since then.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, btrfs has the ability to take snapshots. Also lvm, which is often used on servers because it allows flexibility in managing your disks, has the ability to do snapshots.  But the easiest way to use LVM is to select it when first installing.  See https://www.tecmint.com/take-snapshot-of-logical-volume-and-restore-in-lvm/

The procedure to installing btrfs or LVM depend on which disto you are using.